# What does 'from .. import module' mean?

Tags: python, import, sdl

And I literally mean without replacing the '..'. I have seen this in the PySDL2-0.8.0 library:

```
from .. import sdlimage
```

The reason I ask myself this is because I am trying to run one of the examples they provided and reading the traceback leads me to a file that has this:

```
_HASPIL = True
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    _HASPIL = False

_HASSDLIMAGE = True
try:
    from .. import sdlimage
except ImportError:
    _HASSDLIMAGE = False
```

And of course at some point in the same file:

```
if not _HASPIL and not _HASSDLIMAGE:
    raise UnsupportedError(load_image,
                           "cannot use PIL or SDL for image loading")
```

I do not have PIL (python imaging library) installed, but I do have the sdlimage.py file. So the file I am trying to run is:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sdl2/examples/helloworld.py
```

The path to sdlimage.py:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sdl2/sdlimage.py
```

And the file that raises UnsupportedError(load_image, "cannot use PIL or SDL for image loading"):

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sdl2/ext/image.py
```

I think there is something fishy with these imports...Any ideas?

Comment: See [Intra-package References](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)

Comment: oh wow thats gross ... avoid this if you can... just do normal imports

Comment: @JoranBeasley I did not write it, it's part of the sdl library

Comment: @JoranBeasley I think this is better to use in package, just in case there's another SDL install that comes before the one running in `PATH`. That could cause bugs that are really hard to track down!

Comment: @plg using this import could cause bugs that are really hard to track down ... with proper naming conventions you should have very little to worry about with collisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a relative import. More on this here: http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references